# Yet another doubly linked list

Tags: c++, c++11, linked-list, reinventing-the-wheel

This is a working but very simple doubly linked list. I wrote it to get more familiar with certain language concepts and because I've never made one in C++. (For convenience reasons this is not split into separate files for declaration/definition)

Things I'm mainly interested in:

- Is the overall implementation correct?
- Are the various constructors/operators implemented correctly? I'm still not very sure about these so this is an important concern.
- How is `const` usage?
- Where, if possible, can `constexpr` be used to make this more robust?
- Is this well written/easy to read? What could be improved to make it better in that regard?

and anything else you notice.

**Code:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
#include <initializer_list>
#include <utility>

template<typename T>
class DoublyLinkedList {
public:
    DoublyLinkedList()
        : head{nullptr}
        , tail{nullptr}
        , list_size{0}
    {}

    DoublyLinkedList(std::initializer_list<T> init_list)
        : DoublyLinkedList{}
    {
        for (auto const& value : init_list) {
            push_back(value);
        }
    }

    DoublyLinkedList(DoublyLinkedList const& rhs)
        : DoublyLinkedList{}
    {
        Node* node = rhs.head;
        while (node) {
            push_back(node->data);
            node = node->next;
        }
    }

    DoublyLinkedList(DoublyLinkedList&& rhs) noexcept
        : head{rhs.head}
        , tail{rhs.tail}
        , list_size{rhs.list_size}
    {
        rhs.head = nullptr;
        rhs.tail = nullptr;
        rhs.list_size = 0;
    }

    ~DoublyLinkedList() noexcept {
        clear();
    }

    DoublyLinkedList& operator=(DoublyLinkedList const& rhs) {
        DoublyLinkedList tmp(rhs);
        *this = std::move(tmp);
        return *this;
    }

    DoublyLinkedList& operator=(DoublyLinkedList&& rhs) noexcept {
        if (this == &rhs) {
            return *this;
        }

        clear();

        head = rhs.head;
        tail = rhs.tail;
        list_size = rhs.list_size;

        rhs.head = nullptr;
        rhs.tail = nullptr;
        rhs.list_size = 0;

        return *this;
    }

    bool is_empty() const {
        return head == nullptr;
    }

    int const& size() const {
        return list_size;
    }

    void clear() {
        Node* node = head;
        while (node) {
            Node* delete_this = node;
            node = node->next;
            delete delete_this;
        }

        head = nullptr;
        tail = nullptr;

        list_size = 0;
    }

    void push_front(T const& value) {
        if (!head) {
            head = new Node{nullptr, nullptr, value};
            tail = head;
        }
        else {
            head->prev = new Node{head, nullptr, value};
            head = head->prev;
        }

        ++list_size;
    }

    void push_back(T const& value) {
        if (!tail) {
            push_front(value);
            return;
        }

        tail->next = new Node{nullptr, tail, value};
        tail = tail->next;

        ++list_size;
    }

    void insert_after(int const& position, T const& value) {
        int i = 0;
        Node* node = head;
        while (node) {
            if (i++ == position) {
                Node* new_node = new Node{node->next, node, value};
                new_node->next->prev = new_node;
                node->next = new_node;
                ++list_size;
                return;
            }
            node = node->next;
        }
    }

    void erase(int const& position) {
        if (position <= 0) {
            pop_front();
            return;
        }

        if (position >= list_size - 1) {
            pop_back();
            return;
        }

        int i = 1;
        Node* node = head->next;
        while (node) {
            if (i++ == position) {
                node->prev->next = node->next;
                node->next->prev = node->prev;
                delete node;
                --list_size;
                return;
            }
            node = node->next;
        }
    }

    void pop_front() {
        if (head->next) {
            Node* node = head->next;
            delete head;
            head = node;
            head->prev = nullptr;
        }
        else {
            delete head;
            head = nullptr;
            tail = nullptr;
        }
        --list_size;
    }

    void pop_back() {
        if (tail->prev) {
            Node* node = tail->prev;
            delete tail;
            tail = node;
            tail->next = nullptr;
        }
        else {
            delete tail;
            tail = nullptr;
            head = nullptr;
        }
        --list_size;
    }

    T& front() const {
        return head->data;
    }

    T& back() const {
        return tail->data;
    }

    int find_first_of(int const& start, T const& value) const {
        if (start < 0 || start >= list_size - 1) {
            return -1;
        }

        int position = 0;
        Node* node = head;
        while (node) {
            if (node->data == value && position++ >= start) {
                return position;
            }
            node = node->next;
        }

        return -1;
    }

private:
    struct Node {
        Node(Node* n, Node* p, T d)
            : next{n}
            , prev{p}
            , data{d}
        {}

        Node* next;
        Node* prev;
        T data;
    };

    Node* head;
    Node* tail;
    int list_size;
};

int main() {
    DoublyLinkedList<int> dll{1, 2, 3};
    assert(dll.size() == 3);

    assert(dll.find_first_of(0, 2) == 1);

    dll.erase(1);
    assert(dll.size() == 2);

    dll.pop_front();
    assert(dll.size() == 1);

    dll.pop_back();
    assert(dll.size() == 0);
    assert(dll.is_empty());

    dll.push_back(1);
    assert(dll.size() == 1);
    assert(!dll.is_empty());

    dll.push_back(1);
    assert(dll.size() == 2);

    dll.insert_after(0, 3);
    assert(dll.find_first_of(0, 3) == 1);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `push_front` can be streamlined. The new node will become a head no matter what, and its `next` will point the old head no matter what, so consider

  ```
  void push_front(T const& value) {
      node = new Node{head, nullptr, value};
      if (!head) {
          tail = node;
      } else {
          head->prev = node;
      }
      head = node;
      ++list_size;
  }
  ```

  (Same applies to `push_back`).
- Same technique applies to `pop_front` and `pop_back`, e.g.:

  ```
  void pop_front()
  {
      Node * node = head;
      head = head->next;
      delete node;
      if (head) {
          head->prev = nullptr;
      } else {
          tail = nullptr;
      }
      --list_size;
  }
  ```
- I don't see the value of `push_back` calling `push_front`.
- OTOH, `clear` should call `pop_front`, just like constructors call `push_back`.
- Using `int` as a position is dangerous and limiting. Consider `size_t`.
- `insert_after`, `erase`, and `find_first_of` would benefit from the `private Node * at(size_t position)` utility method.
- The list sorely misses iterators. Once they are implemented, an entire `<algorithm>` library is to your service for free.
- I don't follow why an `int` parameter is passed by a reference.

Comment: I looked at several ways to implement STL compatible iterators none of them were complete. Do you happen to have a good introduction to this topic?